# Show that $G: Z[t] → \mathbb{C}$ defined by $G(f)=f(\sqrt{-1})$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $(t^2 + 1)$ and image the Gaussian integers.

Tags: ring-theory

I'm clear about the ring homomorphism and image part. But I'm not sure how to formulate my language precisely about the statement of the kernel.

Comment: You shouldn't write $\sqrt{-1}$, it is $i$

Comment: $t^2+1$ is definitively in the kernel, so that we can write the morphism $\Bbb Z[t]/(t^2+1)\to\Bbb Z[i]$, which is obviously a bijection.

Comment: (Sometimes one may write that $\sqrt {-1}$, e.g. for not taking a decision of the one or other root of $X^2+1$, just "take one of them, and denote it by $\sqrt{-1}$, then the story should not depend on choice till its end. I did it once for Higgs bundles, and it was needed...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $\langle t^2+1 \rangle\subseteq \ker(G)$. This is easy as $G(t^2+1)=0$. So $t^2+1 \in \ker(G)$, hence the ideal generated by this is a subset of $\ker(G)$.

Now you need to show that $\ker(G) \subseteq \langle t^2+1 \rangle $. Let $f \in \ker(G)$, then $f(i)=0$. Since $f(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$, thus $f(-i)=0$. This means $(x-i)(x+i)=x^2+1$ is a factor of $f$. Thus $f \in \langle t^2+1 \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

For the kernel statement I suggest

With the kernel being the principal ideal generated by $t^2 + 1$